# why is mysqli_fetch_array is separating the array?

Tags: php

I am retrieving values from a MySQL database and am populating them to radio buttons for the user to pick. These are wrapped in a div with the question that is also populated dynamically.  For some reason it populates all the associated answers with the question but the second through fourth answers seem to be separated from the  first answer there's a break only with the first question any idea what would cause this? The following is the code to generate what I am doing:

```
// Connect to the Database
require_once('mysqli_connect.php');

//create the query for the question
$q = "SELECT `Question` FROM tbl_Question WHERE QuestionID = 1";

//Create the query for the Answers
$q2 = "SELECT `Answer`,`AnswerStatusID` FROM tbl_Answer WHERE QuestionID = 1";


//Run the query
$r = mysqli_query($conn,$q);

//run the answer quert
$r2 = mysqli_query($conn,$q2);

//Assign the AnswerStatusID to a var
$AnswerStatusID[] = $row2['AnswerStatusID'];



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo '<div id="Question1"><p>1)' . $row['Question'] . '</p>';
}

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo '<input name="q1" type="radio"value="'.$AnswerStatusID.'"/>' . $row2['Answer'] . '</div><br/>';
}
```

Comment: I'd check your SQL statements first. Remember that the rows returned might not be ordered in the way you want. It's hard to tell how the questions and answers are structured, but if you can take a look at SQL "order_by" you might be able to fix a lot of issues quickly. [MySQL order by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: Can you include what this is actually outputting? I can't quite work it out from your description. Also, do you really need a while loop to print out the question, if there's only going to be one entry?

Comment: There will be eventually more than one question, however, I need this to produce properly before proceeding. @andrewsi I will trya nd take a screenshot and post

Comment: Thank you; you'll need to look at your logic in that case - you'll need to put the `while` loop for the answers inside the one to print out the questions.

Comment: I have a screenshot to try and help to be able to see the ouput that this is creating but no way to post it here that I can see

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issues was with the opening div being in the question echo and the closing div tag in the answer echo. I closed the div in the question echo and added a opening div tag in the answer section and that cleared up the crazy styling and seperation of answers